# i have a loading issue when i add Jquery to the head on the notepad page

Tags: jquery

I use regular notepad when I code. when I make changes to a css file, I save it and refresh IE and I can see my changes right away.

Here's my issue:

When I add Jquery in the head of the notepad page, it takes a while to load so I can see the effects of Jquery.

Is there a way to have it load instantly like my css file?

Thanks.

Comment: css is instant with no jquery file attached.
Jquery attached takes at least 10 seconds

Comment: 10 seconds to load jquery alone is too much unless you have a poor network connection.  Could the problem be elsewhere in your code and executed only when you add jquery?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="ss.js"></script>

that's what I'm using in head.

Comment: ss.js is my jquery file

Comment: And if you remove your `ss.js` file, how long does it take to load?

Comment: it loads normal until I "allow blocked content" which is the Jquery, and then it takes time to load.

Comment: You could try to copy the `jquery.js` on your server instead of referring it on another site (put it beside your `ss.js`).